# How to write a kernel module to lookup route table and arp cache in kernel?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to write a module to lookup the route table in kernel for getting the gateway ip, and use the ip to lookup arp cache for getting the gateway's mac address.

Comment: Why do you need a module? Can't you use iptables ??

Comment: What is your question? And [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I want to write a program and complie it to .ko, while I use insmod to load this module, it will prink the gateway's address. So I should lookup the route table in kernel, but I don't know how can I do it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need a kernel module for this. Everything you need to find the default gw mac address is available in user space...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import socket
from struct import pack

hex_gateway = re.findall('\t00000000\t([0-9A-F]*)\t', open('/proc/net/route').read())[0]
if not hex_gateway: sys.exit(1)

gw_ip = socket.inet_ntoa(pack('I', int(hex_gateway, 16)))

gw_mac = False
for line in open('/proc/net/arp').readlines():
    if line.startswith(gw_ip):
        gw_mac = line.split()[3]
        break

if gw_mac:print gw_mac
else:sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fib_lookup`: looking up route table. Defined at `net/ipv4/route.c`.

`ipv4_neigh_lookup`: using struct neighbour (ARP protocol is implemented by neighbour subsystem) to send the SKB.

Go through `ip_route_input_slow` for more detail about the route table and neighbour subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the mac address of default gateway.After researching bit,I got an answer.
[ip_route_output](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1/source/include/net/route.h#L124) - can be used to check routes
[__ipv4_neigh_lookup](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1/source/include/net/arp.h#L25) - can be used to arp lookup

Example code:

```
    struct rtable *rt;
    struct neighbour *n;
    struct net_device *eth0;
    struct net *ndev;
    unsigned int paddr = 134744072;    //destination ip ex: 8.8.8.8
    unsigned int haddr;
    eth0 = dev_get_by_name(&init_net,"eth0"); //network interface name
    ndev=dev_net(eth0);
    rt = ip_route_output(ndev,paddr,0,RT_TOS(0),eth0->ifindex);
    haddr=rt->rt_gateway;                     //default gateway ip
    printk(KERN_INFO "[G] Default Gateway IP [%d.%d.%d.%d] ",(haddr>>0)&0xff,(haddr>>8)&0xff,(haddr>>16)&0xff,(haddr>>24)&0xff);
    n = __ipv4_neigh_lookup(eth0,rt->rt_gateway);
    printk(KERN_INFO "[G] Default Gateway mac [%pM] ",n->ha); // default gateway mac
```

There are other ways to get default gateway mac.They are based on fib_lookup(). But, they are a little bit long .ip_route_output also call fib_lookup().

```
ip_route_output() -> ip_route_output_key() ->ip_route_output_flow() ->__ip_route_output_key() -> fib_lookup()
```